# How to pin to taskbar specific Control Panel function, for example Edit Power Plan?

Tags: windows, taskbar, shortcuts, control-panel

I would like to pin some Control Panel functions to the Taskbar. I did it for example with "Sounds" via creating a shortcut for

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL "mmsys.cpl"
```

which I got from a StackExchange answer.

However now I would like to pin `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings`.

**Question**

How can I create this specific shortcut? Or more general, if I navigate somewhere in Control Panel, how can I know what is the magic to create a shortcut, what I can pin?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `powercfg.cpl` for Power Options.

Or, for a full list of canonical names of control panel items, you can refer to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/controlpanel-canonical-names) Microsoft article.

To open a specific page, you can use

`%systemroot%\system32\control.exe /name canonicalName /page pageName`

For your use case, you could call the following:

`%systemroot%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.PowerOptions /page pagePlanSettings`

[image]

You can then call this form a shortcut like this

[image]